# JvDataSource's OnRecordChanged Event does not fire

Tags: delphi, jvcl

`JvDataSource` has an `OnRecordChanged` event which, as the name suggests, should be fired whenever current record is changed. But it doesn't fire at all. In fact, even `OnUpdateData` isn't fired at all. I'm beginning to suspect that something is really wrong with either my `JVCL` installation, or `JvDataSource` component. Even a fresh installation didn't solve the mentioned problems. Is anyone out there using `JvDataSource` in their applications at all? And, if yes, have you ever observed such behavior?

---

PS: Before you ask, I have tried all combinations of `DisableEventsOnLoading`, and `EventsEnabled`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on 'TJvDataSourceDataLink.RecordChanged' and trace from there.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I did. The method isn't called at all.

Comment: Indeed. Trying to understand..

Comment: It's working, I have mistaken it for OnDataSetScroll. OnRecordChanged is called whenever the record is edited (changed).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Thanks. I guess it would be better if the event was named `OnRecordModified`

Comment: Yep, it's a bit confusing. See [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataEvent) for what various data events mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Sertac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243614/sertac-akyuz). It was a misunderstanding on my part. `OnRecordChanged` is called whenever the record is edited.